# Calling Clojure from within R?

Tags: r, clojure

Is there any link between R and Clojure?

I am aware of [Incanter](http://incanter.org/), but am ideally looking for an R package for Clojure
or any future plans for one, in order to call clojure from within R.

Comment: I couldn't find one either.  Any chance you'll make one?

Answer (score 4):

Clojure compiles to Java byte code, so you should be able to do what you want using `rJava`. The slightly ugly part would be figuring out what the method signatures are, since `rJava` requires the JNI-style method signature.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Rincanter](http://github.com/jolby/rincanter).